# How to get environment configuration from nx workspace from express

Tags: node.js, express, nx-workspace

In my `nx-workspace` it has 2 `environment.ts` files as `environment.ts and environment.prod.ts`

I am trying to get the base url of `environment.ts`. (which is development) but i could not able to get. what is the correct way to get it?

my try for console:

```
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL); //undefined
  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:' + port + '/api');
});
```

environment.ts file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  MONGO_URL:
    'mongodb+srv://nupdayu.mongodb.net/clinics',
};
```

so what is the correct way to get the current env values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just imported the environment file, it woks fine.

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(environment.MONGO_URL);
  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:' + port + '/api');
});
```